# Node simple-ssh exiting without errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh

I'm trying to connect to an Ubuntu EC2 machine using the Node `simple-ssh` library.

The code:

```
const SSH = require('simple-ssh')
const fs = require('fs')

var ssh = new SSH({
    host: 'my-hostname',
    user: 'ubuntu',
    pass: fs.readFileSync("key.pem")
});

ssh.exec('echo $PATH', {
    out: function(stdout) {
        console.log(stdout)
    }
}).start()
```

When I run `node app.js`, it doesn't output anything. Nor there are any signs of it actually being connected to the machine. It runs for 2-3 seconds and then exits without errors.

Also, I tried entering a random key as the `pass`. And that makes the program run much quicker, which is a sign that the wrong key fails immediately, while the correct one gets somewhere before exiting. But the `exec` command doesn't seem to run. I tried to `mkdir` and the directory didn't appear.

The credentials are 100% correct, I'm able to SSH to the machine via Putty using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh).

> config.host { String }: Hostname
>
> config.port { Number }: Port number (default: 22)
>
> config.user { String }: Username
>
> config.pass { String }: Password
>
> config.timeout { Number }: Connection timeout in milliseconds (default: 10000)
>
> config.key { String }: SSH key
>
> config.passphrase { String }: Passphrase

You should use `key` instead of `pass`

Comment: Haha. That was simple.
Thank you, fixed the problem!